# Cocos3d: glDrawElements EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash

Tags: cocos3d

I am trying to add a walking man pod file into my cocos3d app. I got a blender file for walking man with walk animation from this link for free -> http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/66412
and converted this file to pod and using in the project. when i converted thru PVRGeoPODGUI, i enabled "Export animations" option also. When i converted to .dae thru blender, i enabled 'Apply Modifiers(View)', Include UV Textures, Include Material textures, Copy, Armate options->Export for second life, Collada Options->Use Object instances" options.

I added the code to access this pod file like below.

```
CC3ResourceNode* runner = [CC3PODResourceNode nodeWithName: @"SimpleMan"];
runner.resource.expectsVerticallyFlippedTextures = NO;
[runner loadFromFile: @"AMan.pod"];
runner.location = cc3v(0.0, -10.0, 40.0);
[self addChild: runner];
```

But, i am getting a crash "glDrawElements EXC_BAD_ACCESS" after adding this code in my app. Crash is happening during launch of the scene.

[I didn't had such issues with any other pod's which i am already using which are NOT having any such kind of animation]

Could someone please help me to understanding this crash error and how would i solve it?

Comment: I have not a good idea of your problem but may be project of this link :https://github.com/cocos3d/cocos3d/tree/master/Demos/CC3DemoMashUp may help you.

Comment: I have this project with me already. I am trying similar kind of sample given in the cocos3d demo project. I don't understand why is this crash happening? I even tried commenting out all other code loading other pod's and tried loading only this animated pod, still it is crashing.

Comment: Note: I have now disabled "export skinning data" in PVRGeoPODGUI tool and then converted POD to use in my project. It is not crashing now due to "glDrawElements EXC_BAD_ACCESS". But, animation is NOT working for my animated POD.

Comment: But, i am not sure that i can disable this option or not, because i'm using Armature animation, bone creation and all in Blender model.

Comment: @Getsy did you solve this issue? I had a similar behavior..